# Windows 10 not Showing up in Grub Menu

Tags: 16.04, grub2

I have problem that windows 10 not showing up in grub menu. I used windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04. I have tried run boot-repair, but still not fix. This is boot summary after I run boot-repair :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SHGYzFB38j/

Comment: You have Win10 installed in Legacy mode (incorrectly, I would say) and Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode (correctly). In this situations Grub cannot handle both. The only way to dual-bot is going to UEFI settings.

Comment: Is there reference / tutorial that show what can I do to fix this?

Comment: There is no easy fix in this case due to Windows - not Linux - requirements. Unlike Linux, Windows *strictly* requires a GPT drive for UEFI mode and MBR for Legacy. You have the latter. So, the only real solution is backup your user files, change the drive to GPT (it'll delete ALL partitions) and start over installing both in UEFI mode.

Comment: Allright, mybe I will re-install my windows in UEFI mode, maybe that can fix this problem, right?

Comment: The other option is reinstalling Ubuntu in Legacy mode but UEFI mode is always preferable in UEFI machines. Legacy is for old BIOS.

Comment: Allright @GabrielaGarcia, thank you very much for your help

Comment: When you install Windows in UEFI mode at the present situation.. Windows will take over grub and system will only boot to Windows.. You need to re-install grub to dual boot..